# Create success hook with telegram-bot alert

Tags: python, telegram-bot, dagster

I'm new in Dagster and try to create success hook that will send alerts through a telegram bot. Need help, please

**Resource:**

```
@resource
def send_message(message):
    class TelegramConnection:
        def telegram_resource(message):
            botid = os.environ['telegram_bot']
            chat = os.environ['telegram_chat']
            bot = telegram.Bot(token=botid)   
            return bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=message, parse_mode='HTML')
    return TelegramConnection()
```

**Hook:**

```
def _default_status_message(context: HookContext, status: str) -> str:
    return "Op {op_name} on job {pipeline_name} {status}!\nRun ID: {run_id}".format(
        op_name=context.op.name,
        pipeline_name=context.pipeline_name,
        run_id=context.run_id,
        status=status,
    )

def _default_success_message(context: HookContext) -> str:
    return _default_status_message(context, status="succeeded")

def telegram_on_success(
    message_fn: Callable[[HookContext], str] = _default_success_message,
    dagit_base_url: Optional[str] = "http://localhost:3000",
):

    @success_hook(required_resource_keys={"telegram"})
    def _hook(context: HookContext):
        text = message_fn(context)
        if dagit_base_url:
            text += "\n<{base_url}/instance/runs/{run_id}|View in Dagit>".format(
                base_url=dagit_base_url, run_id=context.run_id
            )
        context.resources.telegram.send_message(text=text)  # type: ignore
    return _hook
```

**Job:**

```
@job (resource_defs={"telegram": send_message}, hooks={success_hook}, op_retry_policy = default_policy)
def job_text_for_pictures():
    bq = extract_ID_with_photo()
    numbers, numbers_withoun_null = extract_id_for_items()
    df_case, df_prod = extract_data_from_sf()
    subset, query = transform_two_df(df_case, df_prod, numbers, numbers_withoun_null)
    final = final_sql_result(query, subset)
    merged_df = result_merge(final, bq)
    load_df(merged_df)
```

**Error:**

dagster._check.CheckError: Member of set mismatches type. Expected <class 'dagster._core.definitions.hook_definition.HookDefinition'>. Got <function success_hook at 0x00000284AC2BB250> of type <class 'function'>.

**UPDATE:**

```
@resource
    def telegram_resource(message):
        class TelegramConnection:
            def send_message(message):
                botid = os.environ['telegram_bot']
                chat = os.environ['telegram_chat']
                bot = telegram.Bot(token=botid)   
                return bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=message, parse_mode='HTML')
        return TelegramConnection()
```

**Job:**

```
@job (resource_defs={"telegram": telegram_resource}, hooks={**telegram_on_success**}, op_retry_policy = default_policy)
    def job_text_for_pictures():
        bq = extract_ID_with_photo()
        numbers, numbers_withoun_null = extract_id_for_items()
        df_case, df_prod = extract_data_from_sf()
        subset, query = transform_two_df(df_case, df_prod, numbers, numbers_withoun_null)
        final = final_sql_result(query, subset)
        merged_df = result_merge(final, bq)
        load_df(merged_df)
```

**Hook:**

```
def _default_status_message(context: HookContext, status: str) -> str:
        return "Op {op_name} on job {pipeline_name} {status}!\nRun ID: {run_id}".format(
            op_name=context.op.name,
            pipeline_name=context.pipeline_name,
            run_id=context.run_id,
            status=status,
        )
    
    def _default_success_message(context: HookContext) -> str:
        return _default_status_message(context, status="succeeded")
    
    def telegram_on_success(
        message_fn: Callable[[HookContext], str] = _default_success_message,
        dagit_base_url: Optional[str] = "http://localhost:3000",
    ):
    
@success_hook(required_resource_keys={"telegram"})
        def _hook(context: HookContext):
            text = message_fn(context)
            if dagit_base_url:
                text += "\n<{base_url}/instance/runs/{run_id}|View in Dagit>".format(
                    base_url=dagit_base_url, run_id=context.run_id
                )
            context.resources.telegram.send_message(**text**)  # type: ignore
        return _hook
```

**New Error:**
TypeError: telegram_resource..TelegramConnection.send_message() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Stack Trace:
File "C:\Users\AlBelyaev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dagster_core\errors.py", line 188, in user_code_error_boundary
yield
,  File "C:\Users\AlBelyaev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dagster_core\execution\plan\execute_plan.py", line 162, in _trigger_hook
hook_execution_result = hook_def.hook_fn(hook_context, step_event_list)
,  File "C:\Users\AlBelyaev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dagster_core\definitions\decorators\hook_decorator.py", line 198, in _success_hook
fn(context)
,  File "C:\DE\dagster\my-dagster-project\my_dagster_project\hooks\text_for_pictures.py", line 50, in _hook
context.resources.telegram.send_message(text)  # type: ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to the result of calling your `telegram_on_success` function to your `@job` definition, something like this:

```py
def telegram_on_success(
    message_fn: Callable[[HookContext], str] = _default_success_message,
    dagit_base_url: Optional[str] = "http://localhost:3000",
):

    @success_hook(required_resource_keys={"telegram"})
    def _hook(context: HookContext):
        text = message_fn(context)
        if dagit_base_url:
            text += "\n<{base_url}/instance/runs/{run_id}|View in Dagit>".format(
                base_url=dagit_base_url, run_id=context.run_id
            )
        context.resources.telegram.send_message(text=text)  # type: ignore
    return _hook

@job (resource_defs={"telegram": send_message}, hooks={telegram_on_success("some_default_success_message")}, op_retry_policy = default_policy)
def job_text_for_pictures():
    bq = extract_ID_with_photo()
    numbers, numbers_withoun_null = extract_id_for_items()
    df_case, df_prod = extract_data_from_sf()
    subset, query = transform_two_df(df_case, df_prod, numbers, numbers_withoun_null)
    final = final_sql_result(query, subset)
    merged_df = result_merge(final, bq)
    load_df(merged_df)
```

Right now by passing `success_hook` to the `hooks=` argument, you're just passing the `@success_hook` wrapper and not your actual success hook definition.

Comment: Thanks, your advice got me further, but I don't understand why two arguments are expected based on new error?

Comment: I thought that when calling telegram_on_success, all the data for the message was taken from _default_status_message and _default_success_message.

Comment: the send_message instance method of your TelegramConnection class either needs to take 'self' as the first parameter, or it needs to be decorated with a staticmethod or classmethod decorator. all instance methods implicitly receive 'self' as their first argument, so when send_message is being called, it's actually receiving the TelegramConnection instance as its first argument.